# What is the best way to unit test a method using ServerSocket class?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, serversocket

I have a such method:

```
public boolean isFree(LdapPort port) {
    boolean result = false;
    try{
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port.getPortNumber());
        ss.getLocalPort();
        ss.close();
    } catch(IOException ex){
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The problem is, that `getLocalPort()` operates on real system ports and during testing it passes depending on the local system.

What should be the valid way to test such method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ServerSocket` instance should be available via factory, which (factory) is [passed as a **dependency**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to your class:

```
// Passing factory dependency via constructor injection
public PortChecker(IServerSocketFactory socketFactory)
{
    this.socketFactory = socketFactory;
}

// ...
ServerSocket ss = this.socketFactory.GetServerSocket(port.getPortNumber());
ss.getLocalPort();
ss.close();
```

Then, in your unit test you can [**mock**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) `socketFactory` to return *fake* server socket and as a result "disconnect" it from any real world systems.

Note that `ServerSocket` might also need to be abstraction (say, represented by interface/base class) so it can be mocked too.

Answer (score 1):

Using PowerMock you can mock constructors, [details](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor). 
So all the calls to the matching constructor of the class you want to mock can return a mock instance that you will prepare in your test.

Your test will require these annotations:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest( ServerSocket.class )
```

Then inside the test method:

```
ServerSocket ssMock = createMock(ServerSocket.class);

expectNew(ServerSocket.class, port.getPortNumber()).andReturn(ssMock); // so constructor of the ServerSocket class taking this specific port number will return the ssMock instance

expect(ssMock.getLocalPort()).andReturn(10); // when method getLocalPort is invoked return 10

reply(ssMock, ServerSocket.class); // do not forget to specify not only the mock instance (ssMock) but the ServerSocket class as well
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into mocking out the serverSocket class.

With your current code the new invocation makes testing hard.

Inject an instance of serversocket into you method/class 
you can then inject a mock instance for testing

I have always found [mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/) a good mocking framework

Answer (score -1):

You can write

```
public boolean isFree(LdapPort port) {
    try{
        new ServerSocket(port.getPortNumber()).close();
        return true;
    } catch(IOException ex){
        return false;
    }
}
```

And you can test it by creating a ServerSocket on the same port and isFree should be false, then close the ServerSocket and isFree should be true.